# Display li child items on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following menu structure:

```
<li id="nav-menu-item-226" class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="http://sample.com/226" class="menu-link main-menu-link">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu menu-odd menu-depth-2">
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="...">...</li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="...">...</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Unordered list has by default `display: none`.

What I need to get done is that whenever user hovers over parent page link, sub-menu would drop down.

In the best case, I would need to get it done with css only. I have tried many different snippets but none of them helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give id to ul tag and give its style display:none.

then,
in your css

> #id ul li:hover > ul `{  display:block }`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
.sub-menu {
    display:none;
}
.menu-item-has-children:hover > .sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4bLeLozm/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also get it work with jQuery to have a nice slideDown/slideUp effect.

jQuery:

```
;(function($){
  $("#menu li:has(ul)").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").not(":animated").slideDown();
  }, function(){
    $(this).find("ul").not(":animated").slideUp();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
#menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="nav-menu-item-221" class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="http://sample.com/226" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Home</a>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-226" class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="http://sample.com/226" class="menu-link main-menu-link">About Us</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu menu-odd menu-depth-2">
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="...">...</li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="...">...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="nav-menu-item-233" class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="http://sample.com/226" class="menu-link main-menu-link">Third</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ektcj9dp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is nest the `<ul>` within your `<li>` element.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's some CSS that will help you get started:

```
* Resets */
nav a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px/1 Verdana;
    color: #000;
    display: block; }
nav a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
nav ul { 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
nav ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Top-level menu */
nav > ul > li { 
    float: left;
    position: relative; }
nav > ul > li > a { 
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;}
nav > ul > li:first-child { margin: 0; }
nav > ul > li:first-child a { border: 0; }

/* Dropdown Menu */
nav ul li ul { 
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none; }
nav ul li ul li { 
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; }
nav ul li ul a { padding: 10px 0; }
nav ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Preview [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/BEhvQ/)